# How to rename auto-named column

Tags: hive, alter-table

I created a table using CTAS, and it now has an automatically generated name (namely, `_c0`). I am unable to rename this using the classical `ALTER TABLE <name> CHANGE _c0 new_name STRING`. How would I rename it?

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
SELECT my_udf(col_1)
FROM other_table
;
```

`my_table` now contains one column: `_c0`.

Attempt to change the column name:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE _c0 my_col STRING;
```

This results in:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:71 cannot recognize input near '_c0' 'my_col' 'STRING' in rename column name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key lies in escaping `_c0` properly:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE `_c0` my_col STRING;
```

This works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Hive treats names that start with `_c` as internal names, which can not be accessed directly by users. When you run `explain some_query`, you will see the usage `_col0` or sth similar.

One workaround is to wrap the column name with backquotes. Or just specify a valid alias for each of those columns created with CTAS, so that no `alter` is needed.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table AS
SELECT my_udf(col_1) AS my_col
FROM other_table
;
```